# Removing and adding "Duration calculation"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-views

I have crated a calendar, and in the form to create the events i have two datePickers like any event form would These Dates can either be the same or different.

If they have matching dates i want a "Duration Calculation" appear in the Time Select Menu like so...

[image]

As you can see it works! But if i change the dates after i have opened the time select menu it will not be removed i need a way to remove and add the duration if the dates are the same or not the same.

This is the code i am using at the moment.

```
            function dateCompare() {
              if ( $('#id_end_0').val() === $('#id_start_0').val()){
                 /* Dates Match, Allow */
                $('#id_end_1').timepicker({
                  'timeFormat': 'H:i',
                  'minTime': $('#id_start_1').val(),
                  'maxTime': '23:30',
                  'showDuration': true
                });
              }else{
                /* Date do not match, Dont Allow Duration */
                $('#id_end_1').timepicker({
                   'timeFormat': 'H:i',
                   'showDuration': false,
                 });
              }
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `timepicker` is already initialized. You just need to update the `option`

```
function dateCompare() {
   if ( $('#id_end_0').val() === $('#id_start_0').val()){
      /* Dates Match, Allow */
      $('#id_end_1').timepicker('option', { 'minTime': $('#id_start_1').val(), 'showDuration': true });
   }else{
      /* Date do not match, Dont Allow Duration */
      $('#id_end_1').timepicker('option', 'showDuration', false);
    }
};
```

I am assuming you have initialized `timepicker` already outside of this function

[Reference](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery)

Comment: Yeah i have, timepicker and datepicker, thank you for this i have been struggling with useing jquery. I'll give this ago now